# Trigger to Avoid Deletion of Last Row of that Value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

So I need a bit of help, I need to create a Trigger that avoids the deletion of the last row of a value

Let's say I have:

```
SubjectID | ModuleNr  
1792      |   1  
1792      |   2  
1222      |   3
```

I want to be able to avoid that the last row of each SubjectID is deleted, so in this case would only be deleted the first row.

I tried different approaches (using `SQL Server 2012`), but I cant use a For Each after my FOR DELETE, neither can I do a BEFORE DELETE.

Every approach I tried has let me delete the row anyway.

Please keep in mind, this is my first semester in SQL, I'm new to this.

here is my attempt using count to somehow see if there is only 1 value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER curriculum.Keep_Last_Module
ON curriculum.Module
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @count AS INT
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM curriculum.Module 
             WHERE SubjectID = (SELECT SubjectID FROM deleted) GROUP BY SubjectID)

    IF (@count = 1)
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Last Module Cannot be Erased',16, 1)
    END
END
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's exactly that, the table must keep at least one row of each SubjectID

Comment: . . But is it specifically the highest value of the module number?  Or just that any must exist after the delete for each subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want it to automatically preserve one in the event that all of the rows for a subject would be deleted.

For that you need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, example below ([DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d35840fdeab248685fb25ea31fc2420f))

```
CREATE TRIGGER curriculum.Keep_Last_Module
ON curriculum.Module
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
      WITH T
           AS (SELECT *,
                      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SubjectID) AS BaseSubjectCount
               FROM   curriculum.Module),
           D
           AS (SELECT *,
                      COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY SubjectID) AS DeletedSubjectCount,
                      MAX(ModuleNr) OVER (PARTITION BY SubjectID) AS MAXModuleNr
               FROM   deleted)
      DELETE T
      FROM   T
             JOIN D
               ON T.SubjectID = d.SubjectID
                  AND T.ModuleNr = d.ModuleNr
                  AND ( T.BaseSubjectCount <> D.DeletedSubjectCount
                         OR D.ModuleNr <> D.MAXModuleNr );

      IF @@ROWCOUNT < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   deleted)
        PRINT 'At least one row was ignored as that would remove the last one for a SubjectID'
  END
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it!
A bit too much for my understanding but I'll for sure will try to understand better what happens in this block of code!
But I'm so thankful, been with this for hours! I cannot thank you enough for your patience :)

Answer (score 2):

I used the following Trigger and it works perfectly in case of one row deletion, and in case of multiple rows deletion it will prevent the whole deletion operation in case of one subjectID will violate this condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER curriculum.Keep_Last_Module
ON curriculum.Module
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    If exists(SELECT SubjectID FROM deleted except SELECT SubjectID FROM curriculum.module)
      BEGIN
      RAISERROR('Last Module Cannot be Erased',16, 1)
      ROLLBACK
      END
    END
END
```

Comment: @MartinSmith i think you're right, i will try to fix it. Also i edited my answer and mentioned that. Thanx in advance

Comment: thank you for the feedback!
but it deletes anyway even after raising the error for me

Comment: instead of count you can use `if exists(SELECT SubjectID FROM deleted except SELECT SubjectID FROM curriculum.module)`

Comment: @MartinSmith i think they gave the same result

Comment: @MartinSmith I tried both and both of them worked in case of one and multiple rows deletion

Comment: `WHERE SubjectID = (SELECT SubjectID FROM deleted)` will definitely fail if a single statement deletes more than one row

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok  now i get what you are trying to mention, i will fix it as you suggested

Comment: @MartinSmith i tested my suggested trigger , and it was working well due to the error since i was deleting multiple rows where the condition is violated but it was preventing the deletion due to this exception :)

Comment: @MartinSmith the "if exists" statement you suggested is raising the error but still deleting the row, is there any possibility that the "FOR DELETE" is the cause of that?

Comment: you also need a ROLLBACK. This is added. RAISERROR doesnt roll back the tran, though THROW would

Comment: @LuísCaldeira check the latest answer update made by Martin Smith

Comment: @MartinSmith with the ROLLBACK it's raising the error and not deleting anything, the duplicate ID is still there :s

Comment: so thats what you want isnt it? you tried to do a delete violating your rule and it rolled it back.

Comment: In the example im using to test i have 2 of the same SubjID and 1 different, the intention is to delete one of the duplicates, but whats happening is neither is deleted

Comment: if you want it to silently correct your delete statement and not delete the last one you need an INSTEAD OF trigger and also define the logic for which one to preserve

Comment: Since this runs by batch and not by row how do I know it's the last one and to preserve it? that goes back to my using of COUNT, but without a For Each count is useless

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep at least one row per subject.  Count the number of subjects "before" and "after":

```
CREATE TRIGGER curriculum.Keep_Last_Module
ON curriculum.Module
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @beforeSubjects INT;
    DECLARE @afterSubjects INT;

    SELECT @beforeSubjects = COUNT(DISTINCT m.subject),
           @afterSubjects = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.ModuleNR IS NULL THEN m.subject END)
    FROM curriculum.Module m LEFT JOIN
         deleted d
         ON m.ModuleNr = d.ModuleNr

    IF (@beforeSubjects <> @afterSubjects)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Last Module Cannot be Erased', 16, 1)
    END;

    DELETE m
        FROM curriculum.module m JOIN
             deleted d
             ON m.ModuleNr = d.ModuleNr;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a row in `deleted` exists for which no record in `module` for the same `subjectid` exists, that has a greater `modulenr`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER keep_last_module
               ON module
                  FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM deleted d
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                             FROM module m
                                             WHERE m.subjectid = d.subjectid
                                                   AND m.modulenr > d.modulenr))
  BEGIN
    THROW 50000, 'The last module cannot be deleted.', 0;
  END;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4bdbb37af3374683b67d0c8ad2bed4dc)